# Is it considered better to use c-like initialization or constructor initialization in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should you use direct initialization and when copy initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293596/when-should-you-use-direct-initialization-and-when-copy-initialization)

I know that both

```
int a = 1;
```

and

```
int a(1);
```

work in C++, but which one is considered better to use?

Comment: In 99.99% of cases, it doesn't really matter.  Use the one you prefer.

Comment: search for 'C++ initialisation vs assignment'

Comment: @wreckgar23:  Both of the examples in the question perform initialization.  Neither performs assignment.

Comment: @James if you search as I suggest then you will get articles such as http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=376876 and questions on stack overflow that explain that

Comment: In C++11 you can also do `int a{1};` with curly braces :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `int` there's no difference. The `int a = 1;` syntax is *copy-initialziation*, while `int a(1);` is *direct-initialization*. The compiler is almost guaranteed to generate the same code even for general class types, but copy-initialization requires that the class *not* have a copy constructor that is declared `explicit`.

To spell this out, direct-initialization directly calls the corresponding constructor:

```
T x(arg);
```

On the other hand, copy-initialization behaves "as if" a copy is made:

```
T x = arg; // "as if" T x(T(arg));, but implicitly so
```

Copy-elision is explicitly allowed and encouraged, but the "as if" construction must still be valid, i.e. the copy constructor must be accesible and not explicit or deleted. An example:

```
struct T
{
    T(int) { } // one-argument constructor needed for `T x = 1;` syntax

    // T(T const &) = delete;            // Error: deleted copy constructor
    // explicit T(T const &) = default;  // Error: explicit copy constructor
    // private: T(T const &) = default;  // Error: inaccessible copy constructor
};
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out an *objective* difference.

Comment: Not having a copy constructor is fine if the class has a move constructor, right?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Yes, with the same non-explicitness requirement, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Both end up being the same when all is 1s and 0s, just be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using primitive types as in your example it doesn't make any difference. With classes the assignment form is theoretically less efficient, as it may involve an additional call to a copy constructor; in practice however I expect this call to be optimized away almost always.

On the other hand the second form may incur in what is known as [C++'s most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), that is a statement like:

```
a b(c());
```

is interpreted as a function declaration rather than a variable definition.

I consider the second problem more worrisome than the first, so I consistently use the assignment style of variable definition.